# Best Way to Disable all users in Dynamic CRM except System Administrators

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

What is the best Way to disable all users in Dynamic CRM except System Administrators?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by this?  Are you trying to keep all non-administrators from accessing the system?

Comment: Yes exactly. Keep all non-administrators from accessing the system.

Comment: Is this in scenario - i'm upgrading system, please do not use it?

Comment: It is while importing solution to prevent users from accessing the system.

Comment: In such case i usually go to IIS manager on front and back end servers, and block all IP address except my machine and servers used in deployment. This way users get 403 error when they try to access CRM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that by "System Administrator" you mean user with System Administrator role assigned, and that you are using CRM on-premise

- Go to Users list, select everyone and disable (if you have more than one page of users, you need to do this for every page). Don't worry, you account will not be disabled, even if selected
- go to advanced find and run query:

  Look for: Users

  add relationship: Security roles 
          add condition:  Security role equals "system administrator"
- results will contain users that have "system adminstaror role". Shouldn't be much of them, so you can enable them one by one.

Now you have everyone, except Admins, disabled

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Sure. You can create custom workflow activity that checks if user has role and disable if not. Then run the thing against everyone. Other option is write application that iterates through all users, checks for role and disable user if role not present. Disabling user is just deactivating record.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the users you want programmatically through SetStateRequest.

Here you can find an exmaple how to disable a crm user:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602914.aspx